# mysql MyISAM vs NDB storege engine for heavy reads

Tags: mysql, myisam, database-cluster

Does NDB support join queries ? I know that NDB is faster then MyISAM and NDB run on memory, but with respect to replication, fail over, wide acceptance of both storage engines I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

It supports joins of course. Speed of joines will rely on indexes and columns you are joining by... 
As far as my practice with NDB it is much better, the 'next generation' from myisam :) 
Not just it is faster, but you can have multiple nodes, inserting/writing at the same time in backend files/processes... 
Only floe is that it doesn't support transactions, but myisam doesn't support too, so you better avoid 'heavy' updates or deletes. 
You can check the comparisons [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) 
Hope I helped :)

Comment: having multiple nodes in the case if ndb have have problems for the join queries

Comment: just if one storage is down, and one node with it, you have another node on second storage working, so MySQL server is still up and running until you fix the problem

Comment: plus one for mysql doc link . very very useful